# Add Event Handler in JScript

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

In the function, `editCell()`, which is called in response to an onclick event of an HTML table cell, I am trying this:

```
    var tbl = [valid table ref];
    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1); // insert at end.
    var newCell = row.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.className = "tblItems newItem";
    newCell.innerHTML = "&#160;&#160;Click to add a property item...";
    newCell.onclick   = "editCell(this);";
```

to create a new, 1-cell row at the bottom of the table, where hte new cell is as if it had been created with:

```
    ...
    <tr>
        <td class="tableItems newItem" onclick="editCell(this);"> 
            &#160;&#160;Click to add a property item...
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

But the onclick is not being raised (or the function ref doesn't respond when it is).

A co-worker says to use:

```
    newCell.onclick = function () {
        editIt(this);
    }
```

but it seems that "...(this)..." will refer to the running context.

What is the right way to add a function the takes an argument, to a newly-created cell reference in JScript?

Must work as far back as IE 8, but only needs to target IE.

Comment: Did you try it or are you just assuming what `this` will be?  http://jsfiddle.net/trfQ2/

Answer (score 1):

```
newCell.addEventListener('click', editCell, false);
```

Or in older IE versions:

```
newCell.attachEvent('onclick', editCell, false);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) explains why using `addEventListener` is better than `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.setAttribute("onclick","editCell(this);");
```

Answer (score -1):

this will refer to newCell. However, you are trying to call the wrong function (editIt instead of editCell)

```js
newCell.onclick = function () {
    editCell(this);
}
```

Comment: The first parameter passed to the onclick function is the event, not the sender.  Naming it sender doesn't change that.

Comment: Johan, Is the situation that the 'this' within the parentheses is not evaluated until the referenced function is actually called?

Comment: @BrianWren when calling a function, the word "this" is a reference to the object that called the function.